# Stationary Increments of a Poisson process

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

> Let $\{N(t),t\geq0\}$ be a Poisson process, i.e. for $t\geq0$ and $n\geq0$, $P(N(t)=n) = \dfrac{e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^n}{n!}$, with $\lambda>0$ a constant. Prove that $$P(N(t+s)-N(t) = n) = P(N(s)=n)$$
>   $\forall\,t,s\geq0$ and $n\geq0$

The idea is prove it without using that the Poisson process has stationary increments.
I try doing
\begin{align*}
P(N(t+s)-N(t) = n) &= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}P(N(t+s)-N(t)=n|N(t)=k)P(N(t)=k)\\
&= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}P(N(t+s)-k=n|N(t)=k)P(N(t)=k)\\
&= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}P(N(t+s)=n+k|N(t)=k)P(N(t)=k)\\
\end{align*}
but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: In Poisson process the numbers of occurrences counted in disjoint intervals are independent of each other http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process

Comment: NARQ. One needs to specify which properties of a Poisson process are assumed and which ones are not.